# Python + cookies + requests --- Can not open a link

Tags: python, python-requests

I need to log into a website using python but the login page requires a sessionID cookie in the request header. Using Google developer tools along with a webclient(hurl.it), I was able to determine the required format of the request header that is acceptable by the webserver:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 85
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: www_amsterdam-dance-event_nl_session=l9Abno8a1UyHPof%2BOyVqk8BxHjesGMi78z6Ot0ZXCCbI%2BxVKqjm30ALTfW%2FR7yKcDaqfEtFOyysTrjIeU8lU5ylv1TOlW6GLHY8jDfKKWSULKsUUJiTh92DbvkuYBuE6zt%2FeLs44lDna6Nz3uMCOaSARN7gCpoSz0TOcFaes8Hk9q6FikP1F9e%2B%2FsMwfUP0RTA0Rc5gJFyJPxHXNCdn%2BT49mhHYnzoIWVlxGHhlaEkZX1PPsYx1xq0BCgpb0WnPViuiZiBnQY2nz%2BBO4Uur0WPNfpSSWZg5Qxz79nYeChlRe16JhYjVOdaiUhnfEvp1jM7h%2BCdR6cUeatd7HGbftRCjINDrVuPeyB5ltVihStmzKEjOmWetI0xNuaNswsPIKKuo%2BV6JFNfdLcA6h3iy1K8o%2FA49tKGMP2rmGe4e5Jec%3Df395212364d1ffc80cf95ebf5abf3b40f9dc6441;
User-Agent: runscope/0.1

email=******%40beatswitch.com&login_token=545a46230b291&password=*****&submission=
```

I have produced the following request using Python requests module:

```
POST /my-ade/login/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.amsterdam-dance-event.nl
Content-Length: 85
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept: */*
User-Agent:  runscope/0.1
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: www_amsterdam-dance-event_nl_session=l9Abno8a1UyHPof%2BOyVqk8BxHjesGMi78z6Ot0ZXCCbI%2BxVKqjm30ALTfW%2FR7yKcDaqfEtFOyysTrjIeU8lU5ylv1TOlW6GLHY8jDfKKWSULKsUUJiTh92DbvkuYBuE6zt%2FeLs44lDna6Nz3uMCOaSARN7gCpoSz0TOcFaes8Hk9q6FikP1F9e%2B%2FsMwfUP0RTA0Rc5gJFyJPxHXNCdn%2BT49mhHYnzoIWVlxGHhlaEkZX1PPsYx1xq0BCgpb0WnPViuiZiBnQY2nz%2BBO4Uur0WPNfpSSWZg5Qxz79nYeChlRe16JhYjVOdaiUhnfEvp1jM7h%2BCdR6cUeatd7HGbftRCjINDrVuPeyB5ltVihStmzKEjOmWetI0xNuaNswsPIKKuo%2BV6JFNfdLcA6h3iy1K8o%2FA49tKGMP2rmGe4e5Jec%3Df395212364d1ffc80cf95ebf5abf3b40f9dc6441;
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

login_token=545a46230b291&password=*****&email=******%40beatswitch.com&submission='
```

When I load the former request header with hurl.it, everything works perfectly and the webserver lets me log in but trying the almost-same request with the same parameters fails in python. While using python's request, the webserver presents an error page. Any help would be highly appreciated. I need a solution desperately.

EDIT:
Here is the code:

```
#Open the login page to get sessionID and login_token
loginURL = "https://www.amsterdam-dance-event.nl/my-ade/login/"
loginReq = session.get(loginURL)
loginSoup = BeautifulSoup(loginReq.text)
loginToken = loginSoup.find('input',attrs={'name':'login_token'})['value']
sessionID= loginReq.cookies['www_amsterdam-dance-event_nl_session']
cookie = 'www_amsterdam-dance-event_nl_session='+sessionID

#Construct the header and post it to the webserver
headers = {'Content-Length':'85','Accept':'*/*','User-Agent':' runscope/0.1','Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Accept-Encoding':'gzip,deflate','Cookie':cookie}
payload = {'email':'*******@beatswitch.com','password':'********','login_token':loginToken,'submission':''}
loggedinReq = session.post(loginURL,headers=headers,data=payload)
```

Comment: add the python code in your question

Comment: @Faisal if it is the same session throughout, then why would you want to add cookies to it. Shouldnt they already be in? COuld you please run the code removing the user specified cookies from the headers and let me know what happens?

Comment: @Md.Mohsin I was under the impression that cookies and headers need to be handled manually. With your hint, I first removed the cookies but it didn't work. Then I removed the headers altogether and let requests handle the headers and cookies and its WORKING NOW!!
But the format of the header is still like the older one. Can't guess why one of them is working while the other is not. But got it working none the less.. Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, thanks to [Md. Mohsin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3642558/md-mohsin). I was trying to handle the request headers and cookies manually while the requests module can handle them by itself. So I REMOVED the following line from the code and let requests take total control, and everything worked as intended:

```
headers = {'Content-Length':'85','Accept':'*/*','User-Agent':' runscope/0.1','Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Accept-Encoding':'gzip,deflate','Cookie':cookie}
```